access population statistics in sensitivity analysis?
I want to run a univariate sensitivity analysis on a few individual parameters in an SEIR-type model to see how they affect disease transmission dynamics. I want to see how changes in the parameter values affect population statistics. However, I cannot figure out how to access the population statistics from the sensitivity analysis experiment.
Under the Main object of my model, I have an agent named population which has a few statistics named NSusceptible and NExposed and the like. These are defined using the conditions agent.inState( Individual.Susceptible ) and agent.inState( Individual.Exposed ) and so on.
In the default simulation, I created a Time Stack Chart and I was able to add these statistics to my chart without problem by calling population.NSusceptible() and the like for the values.
I've tried to recreate the same Time Stack Chart within the sensitivity analysis experiment, but I can't seem to access the population agent. I've tried population.NSusceptible() and Main.population.NSusceptible(), but neither seems to work (I get a population cannot be resolved error).
I've tried playing around with IntelliSense but I haven't been able to figure out how I can access these statistics from within the sensitivity analysis.
Does anyone know how to do this?

You need to "pull" data from your Main into the experiment "after each simulation run", this is a code field in the experiment properties.
Best check some example models on how they do it.
Else, you can try yourself by typing root.population.NSusceptible in the code field mentioned above and do with it what you want :)

root.population.NSusceptible and the like does not work. I've not found any examples models showing how to access population statistics from a Monte Carlo or Optimization experiment. If you know of any, I would greatly appreciate if you could share. I'm also not sure what you mean by "pull" data - could you explain how to do that? I don't see any option like this under the experiment properties.

Try a simple example: new model, just a variable of type double  on Main, set it to uniform(0,100). Create the experiment. In the "On after simulation" code box, type traceln("var="+root.myNewVariable+" for sim run"+getCurrentIteration();. Work off this towards what you need
